# Should the Trebles have been "cut off"?

Tags: plot-explanation, pitch-perfect

Watching *Pitch Perfect* again, and through the riff-off, and it seems like the Trebles broke the rule of "stealing the song by picking off a word that they are singing and making it your first word." In the "Songs about Sex" section, the Bella's are singing "Cause I may be bad, but I'm perfectly good at it", to which a Treble broke in with "Sex, baby. Let's talk about you and me."  Is it Treble favoritism, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After listening to the soundtrack for this movie, I firmly believe now that this may have been a directorial mistake. In the soundtrack, the Treble's steal the song at the appropriate time. However, as stated, in the movie, it's about 4 or 5 words too late.

Answer (score 2):

The lyrics for song being sung by the Bellas:

> 'Cause I may be bad, but I'm perfectly good at it
>   **Sex** in the air, I don't care, I love the smell of it

... and by the Trebles:

> **Sex**, baby. Let's talk about you and me.

So it looks kosher to me as the guy riffed off the next word, *sex*, which was just about to be sung.

Comment: But in the deleted scenes, it states the rule I listed above.  The Bellas didn't sing the word "Sex", and they stole it with that word. Thus they should have been cut off.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P I can't comment on that as I haven't see the deleted scenes. It's a minor nit even if that were true.

Comment: Not as minor as "it" versus "it's", which cost the Bellas.

Comment: @CL4PTR4P Point taken. But that's an in-picture nit and the Bellas thought so too :)